# Combining Data.Tables (R) with a loop or mapply

Tags: r, data.table, mapply

I am new to data tables in R and have managed to get 80% of the way through my analysis. The background is that I want to get the returns of a stock 5 days (before and after), and then 25 and 45 days after they report. I have successfully managed to do it for one set of dates (effectively hardcoding) but when I try and automate the process it falls apart.

I will start with my current formulas and then explain the data.

This formula successfully looks at the data tables and returns the sum that I need. The issue is that datem5 and V1 need to go through a loop (or mapply) to automate the process.

```
CQR_Date[CQR_DF[CQR_Date, sum(CQR), on = .(unit, date >= date1, date <= datem5),
            by = .EACHI], newvar := V1, on = .(unit, date1=date)]
```

I tried this (along with many other variants). Please note the newvar needs to be addressed as well.

```
for (i in 1:4) {
              CQR_Date[CQR_DF[CQR_Date, sum(CQ), on = .(unit, date >= date1, date <= cols[,..i]),
              by = .EACHI], newvar := v, on = .(unit, date1=date)]
```

but get this error

```
Error: argument specifying columns specify non existing column(s): cols[3]='cols[, ..i]'
```

Interestingly, when I try

```
for (i in 1:2) {
 y <- cols[,..i]}
```

There is no issue.

Now in terms of data;

- col just contains the column headings that I need from CQR_Data

  cols <- data.table("datem5", "datep5", "datep20" , "datep45")

CQ_Data has the reporting dates for the stock CQ such as the following

```
 CQ_Date <- data.frame("date1" = anydate(c("2016-02-17", "2016-06-12", "2016-08-17")))
 CQ_Date$datem5 <- CQ_Date$date1 - 5  # minus five days
 CQ_Date$datep5 <- CQ_Date$date1 + 5  # plus five days
 CQ_Date$datep20 <- CQ_Date$date1 + 20
 CQ_Date$datep45 <- CQ_Date$date1 + 45
 CQ_Date$unit <- 1    # I guess I need this for some sort of indexing
```

Then CQ_DF (it is the log returns for the stock) is formed by:

```
 CQ_DF <- data.frame("unit" = rep(1,300))
 CQ_DF$CQ <- rnorm(10)
 CQ_DF$date <- seq(as.Date("2015-12-25"), by = "day", length.out = 300)
 CQ_DF$unit <- 1
```

Before setting them as DT

```
setDT(CQ_DF)
setDT(CQ_Date)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Note this uses

```
  library(data.table)
  library(anytime)
```

A simplified version is:

```
  CQ_Date <- data.frame("date1" = c(10, 20))
  CQ_Date$datep5 <- CQ_Date$date1 + 5  # plus five days
  CQ_Date$datep20 <- CQ_Date$date1 + 10
  CQ_Date$unit <- 1 

  CQ_DF <- data.frame("unit" = rep(1,100))
  CQ_DF$CQ <- seq(1, by = 1, length.out = 100)
  CQ_DF$date <- seq(1, by = 1, length.out = 100)
  CQ_DF$unit <- 1

  setDT(CQ_DF)
  setDT(CQ_Date)

  cols <- c("datep5", "datep20" )

  tmp <- melt(CQ_Date, measure.vars = cols)
  setDT(tmp)

  tmp[CQ_DF[tmp, sum(CQ), on = .( unit, date >= date1,  date <= value), by = 
  .EACHI],newvar := V1, on = .(unit, date1=date  )]
```

The issue is now that the sum does not appear to work correctly. It may have something to do with "variable" variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `mapply` or `for` loop, try reshaping the dataset in long format using `melt`, create sequence between the numbers, perform the join and calculate the `sum`.

```
library(data.table)
cols <- c("datep5", "datep20" )

tmp <- melt(CQ_Date, measure.vars = cols)
tmp <- melt(CQ_Date, measure.vars = cols)
tmp <- tmp[, list(date = seq(date1, value)), .(unit, variable, date1, value)]
tmp <- merge(tmp, CQ_DF, by = c('unit', 'date'))
tmp[, .(newvar = sum(CQ)), .(unit, variable, date1)]

#   unit variable date1 newvar
#1:    1   datep5    10     75
#2:    1  datep20    10    165
#3:    1   datep5    20    135
#4:    1  datep20    20    275
```

If you need the data back in wide format you can use `dcast`.

---

Equivalent `tidyverse` option is :

```
library(tidyverse)

CQ_Date %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = cols) %>%
  mutate(date = map2(date1, value, seq)) %>%
  unnest(date) %>%
  left_join(CQ_DF, by = c('unit', 'date')) %>%
  group_by(unit, name, date1) %>%
  summarise(newvar = sum(CQ))
```

Comment: When I try this the sums are not correct and more to the point the results repeat when the date classification changes

Comment: Can you create a complete example with expected output using which I can verify that my answer gives what you expect ? Currently none of the dates overlap hence all `newvar` is `NA`.

Comment: In your answer change  newvar := V1, on = .(unit, date1=date)] to  newvar := V1, on = .(unit, value=date)]

Comment: I think you need `on = .(unit, date >= date1, date <= value)` since `date1` column is fixed in every join, if I have understood clearly.

Comment: I have removed the dates and just used numeric fields and it still does not seem to work, that is 
      CQ_Date <- data.frame("date1" = c(20, 40, 90))  and  CQ_DF$date <- seq(1, by = 1, length.out = 300)

Comment: Can you update your post with this simplified example? Also in your attempt you use `CQR_Date` and `CQR_DF` whereas the data you share is `CQ_Date` and `CQ_DF` which is confusing. Can you correct that as well?

Comment: I have added a basic example to my question which addresses the issue. The CQR_Date vs CQ_Date are simple names and are not relevant

Comment: It certainly looks on the right path. I just need to see if it works with the dates back in

Comment: Thanks heaps. Managed to get it to work with the dates so it is ideal.